# Tagging questions on Space Shuttle Columbia and STS-107

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

There are currently [58 search results for "Columbia"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+columbia) on space.se (although a few are unrelated to the orbiter), and a large amount of them refer to the Columbia disaster, on mission STS-107.

There are also a few questions centered on the Columbia orbiter only, and not the disaster or the rest of the Space Shuttle program.

Now, there is a [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia) tag. It is assigned to two questions.
There is also [sts-107](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sts-107) as a tag, with only one question (that also has [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia))

Is a mass retagging needed for Columbia? Or should [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia) and [sts-107](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sts-107) be removed instead, because [space-shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-shuttle) optionally coupled with [failure](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failure) is enough?

I personally believe having both [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia) and [sts-107](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sts-107) is redundant and just [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia) suffices, as any question on STS-107 would probably have [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia) too.

Comment: I disagree vehemently! See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

New suggestion:

1. Rename [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia) to [shuttle-columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shuttle-columbia), to allow space for a [columbia-csm](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia-csm) if needed.
2. Make [ov-102](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ov-102) a synonym of [shuttle-columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shuttle-columbia).
3. Merge [sts-107](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sts-107) into [shuttle-columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shuttle-columbia) *without synonymizing*, just to get rid of the [sts-107](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sts-107) tag. If we find that the tag keeps getting recreated, we can revisit making it a synonym.

Comment: I like this. I wonder if `shuttle-columbia` would be better in case later `shuttle-challenger`, `shuttle-atlantis`, etc is needed. When tagging photos I like them to read more general->more specific; `bird->raptor->buteo->red-tailed-hawk`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Good idea.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Edited to include that change.

Comment: I recall seeing @OrganicMarble sometimes use "STS name_of_orbiter" in his answers when referring to a shuttle. Would "sts-columbia" serve any purpose compared to "shuttle-columbia"?

Comment: Also `sts-107` only had one question that was already tagged `columbia` to begin with.

Comment: @Speedphoenix That comes from the official program name "Space Transportation System". We could make that a synonym as well.

Comment: @Speedphoenix Yes, but merge would be better than untag, since we're discussing it. That way we don't have to bump up the question.

Comment: @Speedphoenix Looks like less controversy with this answer, so I'm going to go ahead and do it.

Comment: @Speedphoenix Ok, the actions are all complete, and I also renamed [tag:challenger] to [tag:shuttle-challenger] to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly disapprove of that because Columbia had a long and storied history. It should not be only known because of the accident.

There was also an Apollo command module named Columbia.

I hate it when people refer to the failures by the names of the Orbiters.

If you're going to make "columbia" = "sts-107" then we need "columbia-orbiter" or some such.

Comment: My point isn't to define the Columbia by its accident. My point is to redirect people who are looking to tag a question "sts-107" to the "columbia" tag, because we don't need the additional tag.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify

Comment: I agree with called2voyage. Columbia is *not* defined by STS 107, but every question on `sts-107`, is bound to have `columbia` as well, and having that tag alone wouldn't help much, unless we one day add per-mission or per-failure tags

Comment: To all, including @called2voyage, how about a tag for the Apollo 11 LM along the lines of columbia-ap11-lm & a tag for Columbia space shuttle as columbia-ss or columbia-sts-107 to distinguish between the two? It's a pain having to space craft with the same name.

Comment: @Fred Definitely not columbia-sts-107, for the reason mentioned by Organic, but columbia-shuttle could work.

Comment: @called2voyage: columbia-shuttle works for me

Comment: @OrganicMarble I made a new answer which suggests not making [tag:sts-107] a synonym. You may want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I could see us getting more questions on the Columbia orbiter. I think a merge/synonym of [sts-107](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sts-107) into [columbia](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columbia) would be a good idea, not because they are exactly equal, but because we don't need a separate tag for the subset of questions about specifically mission STS-107.

Comment: I would also like to suggest having `ov-102` and `sts-columbia` or `columbia-orbiter` (as per Organic Marble's suggestion) as synonyms.